# Why is the FEATURED TABLET APPS tab in the Android market not present on my PC?

Tags: google-play-store

As an answer to [my question about applications for bigger Android screens](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8799/what-application-does-make-great-use-of-the-bigger-screens-of-android-tablets/9244#9244), Daniel answered whether I noticed the **FEATURED TABLET APPS** tab in the PC version of the Android market.

[image: Android market tabs showing FEATURED TABLET APPS tab]

However, on my screen, **this tab is not present** :

[image: Android market without FEATURED TABLET APPS tab]

Does anyone know why this tab is not present on my version of the Android market ?

I am **logged in to my market account**, I have a *Samsung Galaxy S* and a *Archos 101 tablet*. Daniel has no tablet, so that can't be the reason.

I am living in *Europe*, so maybe it's a territorial thing ?

Comment: I'm also a European (who doesn't own a tablet) and I can't see that tab whether I'm logged in or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** As per Lie's comment below, it looks to be US-only. The proxy site I use apparently changed to hosting in the UK :P

---

I'm in Canada, and also tried from a <strike>US</strike> UK (my bad) proxy.  It doesn't show up.

A quick Google search shows that the URL for the page with the tablet apps should be https://market.android.com/details?id=apps_tablet_featured.  Using this link directly doesn't work either, whereas https://market.android.com/details?id=apps_featured (the regular featured apps) does.

So I think Google just had it up temporarily and took it down.  Or, if Daniel can still see it, they're doing what Google normally does: rolling out new features slowly, to only some users at a time.

Comment: I'm on Australia, and can't see the tablet tab; but when I tried using [a proxy](http://www.americanproxy.org/) (purportedly claiming to be a US-based one, double checked by whatismyip.com and ip2geolocation.com), the tablet tab do shows up although the site's javascript are broken.

Comment: @Lie I see it via that proxy too. Edited